# Multidimensional Array List show only first item

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I want to read out a multidimensional array list from my XML file. The list is from type DeviceInformationOverview.

The DeviceInformationOverview object contains the attributes Name, Weight and Repetitions.

My first problem is that the value of the name is added to each attribute when the array element is read out.

My second problem is that only the same item is ever added to the list. I don't have 6 different elements but only one element in the list.

I'm not sure if the two problems are connected or if they are two different mistakes.

**Code:**

XML with Array

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <array name="device_0">
        <item name="name">1b</item>
        <item name="weight">5kg</item>
        <item name="repetition">0</item>
    </array>
    <array name="device_1">
        <item name="name">2b</item>
        <item name="weight">5kg</item>
        <item name="repetition">0</item>
    </array>
    <array name="device_2">
        <item name="name">1b</item>
        <item name="weight">5kg</item>
        <item name="repetition">0</item>
    </array>
    <array name="device_3">
        <item name="name">3b</item>
        <item name="weight">5kg</item>
        <item name="repetition">0</item>
    </array>
    <array name="device_4">
        <item name="name">1b</item>
        <item name="weight">5kg</item>
        <item name="repetition">0</item>
    </array>
    <array name="device_5">
        <item name="name">4b</item>
        <item name="weight">5kg</item>
        <item name="repetition">0</item>
    </array>
</resources>
```

**Resource Helper**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import ch.lbuehler.updateapp.R;

public class ResourceHelper {

    public static List<TypedArray> getMultiTypedArray(Context context, String key) {
        List<TypedArray> array = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Class<R.array> res = R.array.class;
            Field field;
            int counter = 0;

            do {
                field = res.getField(key + "_" + counter);
                array.add(context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(field.getInt(null)));
                counter++;
            } while (field != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity**

public class TrainingPlan extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TrainingPlanListAdapter listAdapter;


GridView listView;
List<DeviceInformationOverview> devices = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_training_plan);

    for (TypedArray item : ResourceHelper.getMultiTypedArray(this, "device")) {
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        String deviceName = item.getString(item.getResources().getIdentifier("name", "string", packageName));
        String weight = item.getString(item.getResources().getIdentifier("weight", "string", packageName));
        String repetition = item.getString(item.getResources().getIdentifier("repetition", "string", packageName));
        DeviceInformationOverview deviceInformationOverview = new DeviceInformationOverview();
        deviceInformationOverview.setDeviceName(deviceName);
        deviceInformationOverview.setWeight(weight);
        deviceInformationOverview.setRepetitionCount(repetition);
        devices.add(deviceInformationOverview);
    }

    setTitle("Trainings Plan");

    listAdapter = new TrainingPlanListAdapter(this, devices);
    listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

}

**TrainingPlanAdapter**
It would be create one Element for the ListView.

public class TrainingPlanListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Activity context;
private final List<DeviceInformationOverview> deviceNames;
private Button deviceButton;

public TrainingPlanListAdapter(Activity context, List<DeviceInformationOverview> deviceNames) {
    super(context, R.layout.exercise_overview_item, deviceNames);
    this.context = context;
    this.deviceNames = deviceNames;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View exerciseOverviewItem=inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_overview_item, null,true);

    //this code gets references to objects in the listview_row.xml file
    final TextView weightField = (TextView) exerciseOverviewItem.findViewById(R.id.weightInfo);
    final TextView repetitionField = (TextView) exerciseOverviewItem.findViewById(R.id.repeatitionInfo);
    deviceButton = (Button) exerciseOverviewItem.findViewById(R.id.buttonDevice);

    deviceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent data = new Intent(context, DeviceDetailActivity.class);
            data.putExtra("deviceTitle",((Button)v).getText());
            data.putExtra("actualWeight", weightField.getText());
            data.putExtra("actualRepetition", repetitionField.getText());
            context.finish();
            context.startActivity(data);
        }
    });

    for(DeviceInformationOverview deviceInformationOverview : deviceNames) {
        //this code sets the values of the objects to values from the arrays
        deviceButton.setText(deviceInformationOverview.getDeviceName());
        weightField.setText(deviceInformationOverview.getWeight());
        repetitionField.setText(deviceInformationOverview.getRepetitionCount());

    }
    return exerciseOverviewItem;
}
```

}

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using your known indexes instead of finding the identifier on the line you mention.

```
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceType")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_training_plan);

    for (TypedArray item : ResourceHelper.getMultiTypedArray(this, "device")) {
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        String deviceName = item.getString(0);
        String weight = item.getString(1);
        String repetition = item.getString(2);
```

In your adapter you need to set the Text based on the current position.  getView will be called for each item.
Replace:

```
for(DeviceInformationOverview deviceInformationOverview : deviceNames) {
    //this code sets the values of the objects to values from the arrays
    deviceButton.setText(deviceInformationOverview.getDeviceName());
    weightField.setText(deviceInformationOverview.getWeight());
    repetitionField.setText(deviceInformationOverview.getRepetitionCount());

    }
```

With:

```
//this code sets the values of the objects to values from the arrays
   deviceButton.setText(deviceNames.get(position).getDeviceName());
   weightField.setText(deviceNames.get(position).getWeight());
   repetitionField.setText(deviceNames.get(position).getRepetitionCount());
```

Comment: Thank you it's solved the problem with the same values in my attributes. But in the List is only show one item, it's the last one. Do you have also an idea for this problem?

Comment: I've added in the question

Comment: I updated answer, I think this should solve your issue with only displaying the last item.